# Spellcasting Prodigy Feat in Pathfinder - yes or no?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

My player asked me about using this feat on his new first-level character.

> *Spellcasting Prodigy - Treat primary spellcasting ability score as 2 higher for bonus spells and save DCs.* This feat is from **Player's Guide to Faerun** from 2004.

However, I found out that, after errata, it doesn't affect save DCs.

It feels bit overpowered and it is from D&D 3.0. How should I, if it is possible, convert it for Pathfinder?

Disscusion about this feat [here](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?79418-Spell-Casting-Prodigy-%28FRCS%29) and [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19569458/Spellcasting_Prodigy_question).

Comment: Does it increase the CL higher than level?

Comment: @C.Ross it doesn't increase CL.

Comment: @Ernir Ah, just the extra bonus spell, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, using updated D&D material is recommended over the original material. Wizards of the Coast didn't do this a lot in 3.0/3.5's product lifecycle, but when they did, there was usually a reason for it. (Exception: Things like the Tome of Battle Errata, which is obviously broken.) **Personally, I'd not allow the 3.0 version** on these grounds alone - the 3.5 version has mechanically overridden it.

But in this case, your primary concern seems to be "balance" rather than it coming from 3.0. Whether the feat is "balanced" for your game is going to depend heavily on your definition of the term. [See this question on what makes something overpowered.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-makes-a-character-creature-power-ability-etc-over-powered) Using @mxyzplk's definitions, I'd say this feat *is* trivially overpowered (compare: Spell Focus), but I doubt it is contextually overpowered (it does not provide unusual power in one specific context, the bonuses are highly generic) or even practically overpowered (an extra spell and/or +1 to save DCs isn't going to make a non-dominating character suddenly dominate). Using @Brian Ballsun-Stanton's definition, I'd call it somewhere between balanced (it's certainly useful for most, but hardly mandatory) and underpowered (if your casters are rocking out on metamagic feat chains, taking Spellcasting Prodigy is just a speed bump on the road to power) in a 3E + PF game, depending on the optimization level of your group.

Answer (score -1):

I find that the new trait, [Magical Knack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-knack), strikes the best balance of the intent of the original Spellcasting Prodigy feat.  This allows you to have a +2 bonus to your caster level for one class, so long as it doesn't increase your caster level above your maximum Hit Dice for your character.  So it doesn't even affect the character until at least 2nd level.  My current character is a wizard 8/fighter 1, with this trait.  So he doesn't get 5th level spells yet, but the spells he does have he casts as if he were 9th level.  I find the balance is working well and it isn't overpowered to any extent.

As with Ernir, I would not allow the 3.0 version.  If the character wants something that affects his relevant ability score, make them earn their levels and gold and buy or find a magical object such as an ioun stone or amulet or intelligence.  For a first level character, the immediate bonus is too overpowered.