# Is the Cancer Mage overpowered?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, balance, prestige-class

I am running a D&D 3.5 campaign, and a player wants to go for the Cancer Mage prestige class in the *Book of Vile Darkness*. Is this prestige class overpowered, as defined in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-makes-a-character-creature-power-ability-etc-over-powered)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Cancer Mage is one of the most notoriously-overpowered classes in the game

Only the illithid savant and beholder mage immediately come to mind as more powerful. The ability to ignore the negative aspects of diseases, but *only* the negative aspects, is **extremely** powerful, because many diseases *do* have some kind of “upside” (to make diseased creatures more dangerous, I suppose). Worse, several of these have *cumulative* upsides: something it keeps improving (until it kills you).

In particular, Festering Anger is supposed to keep improving your Strength until it kills you – except it will never kill a cancer mage. So the cancer mage just gets arbitrarily-high Strength. Vile Rigidity is another one, that keeps improving your natural armor. Note that both of these diseases are in *Book of Vile Darkness* right alongside the cancer mage, so... I suppose someone wasn’t paying attention.

That said, without these and other abusive diseases, the cancer mage is probably OK. Drawing the line between what is an abusive disease and what isn’t is tricky though.

Comment: Upon rereading disease host, it seems *extremely* likely that it's supposed to be *just* disease immunity except the CM's still a carrier. But assuming a traditional reading, besides the GM fiat-heavy festering anger and the admittedly problematic vile rigidity, are there *other* problematic diseases? Seems sad to consign an otherwise interesting and flavorful class to the scrapheap when the DM can instead just say *No* to a pair campaign elements under his control anyway.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I do not, off-hand, know of any other problematic diseases, but at least for the sake of this answer I’m not comfortable assuming there aren’t any. Diseases are *deep* into that “the designers always assumed players wouldn’t be messing with this and gave no thought to what would happen if they did” category.

Comment: Reading the BoVD, it does specifically mention its only the cosmetic effects that effect the Cancer Mage with Disease Host - so in the case of Festering Anger, surely they would just get the pustules, but *none* of the other effects - and just act as a carrier?